# What is the advantage of describing functions in terms of polar coordinates instead of Cartesian coordinates?

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

Using $x = rcos(\theta)$, $y = rsin(\theta)$, we can rewrite $x^2 = y$ as $r = sin(\theta)sec^2(\theta)$

This seemed very unnecessary while I was learning calculus. Does anyone know if there are specific instances where it is advantageous of describing Cartesian functions in polar coordinates aside from drawing pretty intersecting curves?

Comment: ${\displaystyle \int\limits_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx}$

Comment: One benefit of polar coordinates is that it gives an alternate definition of complex numbers that shows that they are deeply related to rotation. Polar coordinates also allow for easier integration when you are trying to describe different areas. Say like the wall of a cylinder. It is at times easier to integrate in polar than in cartesian coordinates.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin I read somewhere that the technique for integrating that function was basically limited to that specific integral. Not sure how true that is though.

Comment: Anytime you want to integrate something that is radially symmetric.

Comment: The two coordinate systems are intimately connected. @Eoin is right on the money--if you ever have to deal with complex variables, you can't escape a thorough familiarity with polar coordinates. Embrace them, don't always try to translate back to familiar Cartesian coordinates. (+1, @Eoin)

Comment: The parabola $y=x^2$ is happy with rectangular coordinates. The circle with centre the origin is more comfortable with polar, as are a number of other curves, such as the cycloid. A good deal of physics is more pleasant in polar.

Comment: So-called "Turtle Graphics" are also naturally polar in nature, at least piecewise.

Comment: $x\mathrm{d}y-y\mathrm{d}x=(x^2+y^2)\mathrm{d}\theta$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

many times integrating over a certain region such as a circle in cartesian coordinates would require you to set up two integrals whereas in polar coordinates the integral would be much simpler to compute.